# Barney Stinson on moving and helping move

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In HIMYM s2e16 Lily gives Barney a flier for her play, he says:

> Asking someone to come see your play is like asking someone for a ride
>   to the airport or to crash on your couch or to help you move. Call a
>   cab, book a room, **hire some movers** ...

But in a later episode he not only asks his friends to help him and his brother and mother pack and move, but actively manages to pursue them to help, even though they were reluctant.

Is there some explanation by the producers, why Barney was so much against it in one instance, and suddenly had a change of heart at a later point?
Or is it just plot development, and the only way they could have them discover James' dad was in this particular setup, going against something Barney believes in?

Comment: It could be he's just a hypocrite.

Answer (score 4):

You're gonna have to realize quite soon that Barney doesn't believe in many things, especially early in the series. He just believes in whatever goes his way at this exact moment.

Like Breno said, this special case is very close to hypocrisy, and maybe even **selfishness** and **egocentrism**.

This is a typical **do as I say, not as I do** scenario.